# How to disable Ripple + hover effect from a mat-button in Angular Material 15

Tags: angular15, angular-material-15

I'm using Angular 15 with Material 15 and trying to add a button without ripple effect / any hover effect's.

This used to work in angular material 12:

`<button mat-button [disableRipple]="true">DoSomething</button>`

But now it's still showing ripple / hover effect's. Is the "disableRipple" input broken?

I can remove this behavior by doing:

```
.no-hover-effect {
  &.mat-mdc-button {
    ::ng-deep {
      .mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple, .mat-mdc-button-ripple {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like a solution without having to modify the css.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been fixed in angular 16. See [bug report](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27507).

Comment: This is great if we ever decide to upgrade our project. Right now our project consist of many small packages. Each package is kind of a mini website. We have 1 app loading these packages. So if we want to use angular 16 we should upgrade all of them to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hover can't be disabled this way.

try

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-checkbox span.mat-checkbox-ripple {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Hover is not intended to be disabled, because accesibility:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8298#issuecomment-354753835

Comment: This is what i posted in my question. So i know this works. But the question is how to do this without creating (css) dependencies on the angular classes.

Comment: you're right. excuse me. I put the comment from dev that this will not be adressed.